# Dynamic Prototype cell drop down style menu

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a dynamic Prototype Table View with 7 cells within it. I am looking for a way to make the last cell a drop down menu. The last cell will be called policies and hopefully break into the actual polices by being a drop menu / sub menu. Hopefully this makes sense. I am using swift and latest iOS.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: There's two main opions: use popover on normal/large devices or navigate to the next screen on compact/normal devices; add/remove extra cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this link from github hopefully it will help people out in the future. https://github.com/fawazbabu/Accordion_Menu